# Database file created, no data/schema

Tags: python, sqlite, scapy

The .db file gets created inside the provided path. The printed output shows in the terminal window, but there is no data/schema inside the .db file. No errors come up, syntax seems right. Here's the code. I'm at a loss as to why,`conn.commit()` are in the correct areas. Any information would be greatly appreciated.

```
from scapy.all import *
from scapy.layers import dhcp
import logging
logging.getLogger("scapy.runtime").setLevel(logging.ERROR)
runtime = logging.getLogger('scapy.runtime')
runtime.setLevel(logging.ERROR)
loading = logging.getLogger('scapy.loading')
loading.setLevel(logging.ERROR)
from scapy.layers.l2 import Ether
from scapy.layers.all import BOOTP
from scapy.layers.all import DHCP, DHCPTypes, DHCPOptions, DHCPRevOptions
from scapy import route
import urllib
import urllib3
from urllib.request import urlopen
import os
import sqlite3
from datetime import datetime
import sys


DIR_NAME = os.path.dirname(__file__)
db_path = os.path.join(DIR_NAME, "/home/dtman/Desktop/Secure_DHCP  /secureDHCP-DB.db")

conn = sqlite3.connect(db_path)
c = conn.cursor()
conn.commit()


def make_table():
   c.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS secureDHCP(mac VARCHAR(50), vendorId VARCHAR(50), time VARCHAR(50), oData VARCHAR(50)')
   conn.commit()
   c.close()
   conn.close()


def the_data():
   mac = src_mac()
   vendorId = vendor()
   time = timeData()
   oData = optData()
   c.execute("INSERT INTO secureDHCP (mac, vendorId, time, oData) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)",
          (src_mac, vendor, timeDate, optData))
   conn.commit()


s=socket.socket(socket.PF_PACKET, socket.SOCK_RAW, socket.ntohs(0x0800))

print("Input network interface")
interface = input()


def pkt_data(pkt):
    src_mac = pkt.getlayer(Ether).fields['src']
    url = 'http://api.macvendors.com/' + src_mac
    r = urlopen(url)
    vendor = r.read()
    timeData = str(datetime.now())
    full_options = pkt.getlayer(DHCP).fields['options']
    dhcp_options = [o for o in full_options if isinstance(o, tuple)]
    for x in dhcp_options:
        if x[0] in ('message-type', 'requested_addr', 'hostname'):
            optData = x[1]
            print('MAC: {} /// Vendor: {} /// Time {} /// optData: {}'.format(src_mac, vendor, timeData, optData))

sniff(iface=interface, prn=pkt_data, filter='udp port (67 or 68)', store=0)
```

Output in terminal:

```
`MAC: 00:00:00:00:00:00 /// Vendor: b'BRAND, Inc.' /// Other Data: 3
 MAC: 00:00:00:00:00:00 /// Vendor: b'BRAND, Inc.' /// Other Data: 192.168.1.4
 MAC: 00:00:00:00:00:00 /// Vendor: b'BRAND, Inc.' /// Other Data: b'HOSTNAME'`
```

Comment: Can you post the printed output?

Comment: I meant, can you edit your question and add the printed output... comments ate not the appropiate place for that ammount of code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all, you didn't call the method like `make_table()`.Second，you call `make_table()`
and inside it,why close the `conn`?how your`the_data()`insert the date?Please give the min sample.something like below will never wrong.

```
conn = sqlite3.connect(db_path)
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS secureDHCP(mac VARCHAR(50), vendorId VARCHAR(50), time VARCHAR(50), oData VARCHAR(50)')
conn.commit()
c.execute("INSERT INTO secureDHCP (mac, vendorId, time, oData) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)",
      (src_mac, vendor, timeDate, optData))
conn.commit()
c.close()
conn.close()
```

Comment: I had to restructure your code around my code, but I got it work. Cheers!

Comment: I am too new to mark this answer as useful. But will upon achieving reputation. Cheers.